# Dynamic function call in Racket; or get a procedure from a string

Tags: dynamic, scheme, lisp, racket

I apologize in advance for this likely silly question :)

Suppose, I have a list of strings like

```
(define func-names '("add" "sub" "mul"))
```

And there are also functions defined like so

```
(define (add x y)
  (+ x y))

(define (sub x y)
  (- x y))

(define (mul x y)
  (* x y))
```

As you can see, values of the strings in the list correspond to the names of the functions. 
I need a way to iterate through the list and call the function that corresponds to a string value. Something like

```
(define (all-ops x y)                                        
  (map (lambda (name) (string->proc name x y)) func-names))
```

where `string->proc` is what I'm looking for. Something like Ruby's `send/public_send` method, if you're familiar with Ruby.

I'm mostly interested in answers applicable to Racket.

Thank you.

EDIT;
And I've forgotten to mention that there may be a million of function names, so `cond`, `match` would be tedious to use here.

Comment: This is one of those cases where it can be *extremely* dangerous to use `eval`, if `func-names` is coming from a user. They could easily throw in `delete-file` or `subprocess` or anything they want, and you'd end up executing it.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me of this. I'm going to use `eval` internally, so that a user won't be able to use malicious input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider making a hash table that maps strings to function values.

That said, you can do as follows:

```
#lang racket
(define (add x y)
  (+ x y))

(define ns (variable-reference->namespace (#%variable-reference)))

(define (string->procedure s)
  (define sym (string->symbol s))
  (eval sym ns))

(string->procedure "add")

((string->procedure "add") 1 2)
```

See also http://blog.racket-lang.org/2011/10/on-eval-in-dynamic-languages-generally.html